# '{"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}}'

Tags: android, quickblox

Hello everyone i am trying to upload user profile pic it shows me 
    **'{"errors":{"base":["Forbidden. Need user."]}}'**
this error Please let me know what i am doing wrong

```
QBContent.uploadFileTask(profilePic, true, new QBCallbackImpl() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // get uploaded file 
            QBFileUploadTaskResult fileUploadTaskResult = (QBFileUploadTaskResult) result;
            QBFile qbFile = fileUploadTaskResult.getFile();
            int uploadedFileID = qbFile.getId();

            // Connect image to user
            QBUser user = new QBUser();
            user.setId(userID);
            user.setFileId(uploadedFileID);

            QBUsers.updateUser(user, new QBCallbackImpl() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result result) {
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
                        // Profile picture has changed!
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString()); 
                    }
                } 
            });
        } else {
            Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString()); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: your are not save his session from Login if you save then use it

Comment: everyone i know has problem with Quickblox..

Answer (score 1):

there are two senario
1)you are not a logged in user 
2)or may be session you created is expired 
for that purpose you need to signin with quickblox  again

Answer (score 0):

Either you do not have required permission there. or you are not a registered user.

Comment: i dnt know how to pass permition i ma new for qucik bloxl

Comment: please let me know how to add permitions

Comment: There is no need some other permissions for this. use his session which you have already created at login time Application.....etc like session saved ...

Answer (score 0):

You should login your user again and only after that attach the file.I had similar situation when i took a picture using camera. I did this.
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivity(intent);
CameraActivity was started and connection was lost, so you need to reconnect if you want to upload the file.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this before calling upload

```
QBUsers.signIn(Constants.user);
```