# Base Forbidden. Need user

Tags: android, chat, history, quickblox

I am using **QuickBlox SDK** to load chat history. Like this:

1. Create Session
2. after successfully creating section Initialize chatService
3. Login chat Service
4. After successful Login.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
QBRequestGetBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
customObjectRequestBuilder.setPagesLimit(ConstsCore.CHATS_DIALOGS_PER_PAGE);
try
{
    List<QBDialog> chatDialogsList = QBChatService.getChatDialogs(null, customObjectRequestBuilder,bundle);
} catch (QBResponseException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At this step I am getting this Exception:

> base Forbidden. Need user.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968544/errorsbaseforbidden-need-user ?

Answer (score 0):

Chat it's a real time protocol

but chat dialogs retrieval is a REST API, so you have to login via REST API as well to use REST API requests

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Sign_In_with_login_.26_password